# React JS - state management

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

I have been learning React recently, I tried to build a small web-app for learning React. I have doubt regarding the state management.

I am not using anying library for state management now and also I am not using any DB. I want to understand which is best way to maintain state.

```
// index.js 
...
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<App/>}></Route>
    <Route exact path="/cart" element={<Cart/>}></Route>
</Routes>
...

// App.js
function App() {
    ...
    // fetch Product data -> productData
    // update Cart data -> cartData
    <Product data={productData} {updateCart} />
    ...
}

// Cart.js
function Cart() {
    ...
    <Cart data={cartData} />
    ...
}
```

Consider on the above snippet.

I have two page

Product page

Cart Page

I am fetching the data in Product page and when the product is added to the cart then I will update 'cardData'. Now I want to use the 'cartData' in the Cart page.

What is the best way to achieve it ? I thought about storing it in cache. If there is DB we can store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd use a wrapper to manage state and API calls. But if you have multiple pages that need access to the same state then look [into react useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) which is essentially a way of creating a global state.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario the best way to store your data would be the `localStorage`. There you should define a key for the cart, and your value would be an array with the products in your cart.

In ReactJS this is how you can access the `localStorage`:

```
//for reading the 'cart' value
localStorage.getItem('cart');

//for writing the 'cart' value
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(products));
```

As you said, if you have DB, you should store your this data in DB.

Comment: I had this idea of localStorage. But someone has said it defeats the purpose of state management propagating through props. I think in this case it might be valid, since this is not ideal solution for app.

Comment: localStorage isn't a state management solution, it is a data persistence solution. There is no (native) way to subscribe to updates for local storage entries